# ¿Cómo montar otro sitio web en un mismo servidor Nginx?

Tags: php, servidor, nginx

Tengo 2 páginas webs y quiero montarlas en el mismo servidor pero no sé como. Intenté a la forma que pensaba que funcionaba pero aveces una página web funciona y la otra no, o ninguna funciona.

Comment: Revisa la sección "Server" en tu archivo de configuración de nginx: https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx/#server-blocks La idea es que tengas un bloque de "server" por cada sitio (utizando un puerto diferente para cada uno, en este enfoque).

Comment: Yo uso fastcgi, cómo sería en ese aspecto? Los dos servers están utilizando el puerto 443.

Comment: bueno, hasta donde se, tendrías que utilizar puertos diferentes. Revisa este gist, quizas te ayude: https://gist.github.com/apollolm/23cdf72bd7db523b4e1c

Comment: esos sitios están en diferentes dominios o subdominios?

Comment: @amenadiel están en diferentes dominios en el mismo servidor

Answer (score 4):

No necesitas usar puertos diferentes. Si ambos sitios tienen su certificado SSL, tendrás que usar el puerto 443 para ambos, dado que pedir https://sitio1.com y https://sitio2.com siempre va a buscar el puerto 443.

Configurar puertos distintos (supongamos que a uno le pongas 8443) no podría llamarse más que como https://sitio2.com:8443 y no es la idea.

Lo que haces es que en tu carpeta `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` tienes ambos vhosts y las peticiones discriminan según el hostname que pide el visitante:

```
/etc/nginx
  - sites-enabled
    -  sitio1.com.conf # el nombre del archivo da igual, pero es más ordenado
    -  sitio2.com.conf
```

En cada uno especificas un `server_name` y con eso el vhosts sólo responderá a peticiones que calcen con su nombre. En el ejemplo siguiente presta atención a dos disclaimer:

- Estoy usando fastcgi escuchando en un sock, tú podrás cambiarlo para que escuche en un puerto TCP si quieres.
- Puse un certificado tipo Let's Encrypt, tú debes tener algo equivalente supongo

---

```
# sitio1.com.conf responde a https://sitio1.com/ y de ahí hacia adentro
server {
    server_name  sitio1.com ;
    root   /var/www/sitio1.com;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/sitio1_error.log;
    index index.html index.php;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }


  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    root /usr/share/;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitio1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitio1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

El sitio 2 es más o menos igual:

```
# sitio2.com.conf responde a https://sitio2.com/ y de ahí hacia adentro
server {
    server_name  sitio2.com ;
    root   /var/www/sitio2.com;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/sitio2_error.log;
    index index.html index.php;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }


  location ~ \.php$ {
    # lo mismo que el otro
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitio2.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitio2.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

sólo cambias el server_name.

Ahora bien, si acaso alguien pide directamente la IP de tu máquina, tú podrías decir que por defecto responda el sitio 1, en cuyo caso el `listen` sería

```
listen 443 ssl default_server; # Sólo uno de los dos puede ser default!!
```

**Opcional:**

La verdad me parece más sano poner un vhost aparte que [rechaza peticiones sin un hostname de tus sitios](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names).

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
server {
  # Default server for all incoming HTTP and HTTPS connections.

  # IPv4
  listen  80        default_server;
  listen  443  ssl  default_server;

  # IPv6
  listen  [::]:80        default_server;
  listen  [::]:443  ssl  default_server;

  # access_log es opcional, pero sirve para mirar quien está haciendo peticiones extrañas
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/default_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/default_access.log;

  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;


  location / {
    return  444; // No content
  }
}
```

Ojo, para que reciba (y rechace como corresponde) las peticiones SSL, vas a tener que poner un certificado autofirmado como el snakeoil que puse ahí).